# Java decode JPEG 2000 to BufferedImage, ImageIO doesn't support JP2

Tags: java, decode, bufferedimage, jpeg2000

I've been working on a Java project for the past two months that involves accessing satellite image from servers and doing some image processing. Almost all the code is finished, except for the fact that I haven't found a way to actually load the images into a buffered image. They are JPEG 2000 images, and I've searched all over the internet for any implementations for decoding jp2 files. Apparently ImageIO.read won't cut it. I did come across the java advanced imaging API (JAI), but I'm looking for any way to do this without using a third party. I also checked out JDeli and JJ2000, but my attempts to use them were unsuccessful.

Is there any way to decode these files? If that's asking too much, is there an easy-to-use library out there that handles this? Also, out of curiosity, why is it so difficult to find an implementation of a jp2 decoder for java?

Comment: Q: *"why is it so difficult to find an implementation of a jp2 decoder for java?"* A: Software patents and licensing issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use imageio-openjpeg library as plugin for the ImageIO API. (https://github.com/dbmdz/imageio-jnr)